# Expression illegal in evaluator

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm trying to code something but there is happening something I don't understand.

I get some values from a database and loop over them and change some of them if needed.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
if qryGeneral.fieldbyname('B_PRIJS').IsNull or 
   qryGeneral.fieldbyname('B_PRIJS').Value = 0 then
begin
   if (qryGeneral.fieldbyname('V_PRIJS').Value <> 0) or 
      (qryGeneral.fieldbyname('V_PRIJSEXCL').Value <> 0) then
   //make some calculations and save data
end;
```

`B_PRIJS` is a float, null type in a SQL Server DB. When I set a breakpoint and I hover .Value it shows 0,11. When I hover IsNull it shows False, so far so good.

Now I would expect it would NOT enter the if-structure, because it is not null and not equal to 0, but it does enter the if-structure.
I don't understand why, I always coded like this.

When I select `qryGeneral.fieldbyname('B_PRIJS').Value = 0` while still being in debug mode, I get a message "Expression illegal in evaluator".

I tried replacing `Value` into `AsFloat` or changing 0 into 0.0 but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong or not understanding here?

Comment: You are comparing a float to an integer, so `0,11` truncates to `0` - hey that matches! `AsFloat` and `0.0` are correct to use, but remember that floating point values are inheritantly inaccurate by nature, so direct comparisons like `AsFloat = 0.0` will not work if `Value` is really small like `0.000000001`. You need to compare using an epsilon instead so you can account for such variations. The RTL has utility functions in the `Math` unit for that, eg: `uses Math; if IsZero(AsFloat) then`.  "*IsZero: These will return true if the given value is zero (or very very very close to it).*"

Comment: @remy Worth saying that these strange comparison rules are special to variants. What's more, exact comparisons is very often precisely what you want. Stating that comparison up to epsilon must be used is wrong. It's very common for `0.0` to be used as a sentinel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Delphi's operator precedence rules](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence) mean that your expression is evaluated like this:

```
if (qryGeneral.fieldbyname('B_PRIJS').IsNull or qryGeneral.fieldbyname('B_PRIJS').Value)
  = 0 then
```

Put parentheses around your `=` expression just like you have around you `<>` expressions, and you should get closer to the results you expect. However, the `Value` property is a `Variant`. When comparing a `Variant` to an `Integer`, the `=` operator will cause the `Variant` to be converted to an `Integer`. [Delphi's variant-type-conversion rules](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variant_Types#Variant_Type_Conversions) show that a `Variant` holding a real value will be rounded to the nearest integer when the target type is an integer, so your 0.11 value will be rounded to zero. Consider comparing to 0.0 instead.

Comment: Ouch. One wonders who decided it would go that way. Would make far more sense to promote integer to a real and then compare.

Comment: @David, that would make sense if the compiler knew in advance that the variant argument held a real, but it can't know that. The safest compiler-automated alternative would probably be to convert the integer to a variant, and then use variant equality rather than integer equality. But then we'd probably be up in arms about how eager the compiler seems to be to convert everything to variants all the time.

Comment: I personally think that variant equality would be better.

Comment: @RobKennedy I could detect the value 0.11 when hovering, so I would guess I does know it contains a real...
But so it seems it doesn't, so I'll work my way around it, tnx!

Comment: Just did a quick test using _(qryGeneral.fieldbyname('B_PRIJS').IsNull) or (qryGeneral.fieldbyname('B_PRIJS').Value = 0.0)_ and now it does what I expect. I'm gonna do some more test just to be sure, but it seems  I'm running again.

Comment: additional: although the code does what I expect, I still get the message while hovering "Expression illegal in evaluator".